# unable to insert form in template: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I try to insert form in template and get an error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'I don't understand

my form (BillForm) is based on a model (Orders) and I just want to display one of it fields (split_bill) in my index template that is a table

I have look for this error in documentation and here on stackoverflow but did not understand the issue...

forms.py

```
class BillForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['split_bill',]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
 
    orders = Orders.objects.filter(paid = False) # only ongoing orders (not paid)
    if request.method == "POST":
        billform = BillForm(request, data=request.POST or None)
        if billform.is_valid():
            billform.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        billform = BillForm(request) 

    return render(request, 'cafe/index.html', {'orders':orders,'billform':billform,})
```

index.html

```
<div class='container'>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <table id="table_id" class="table  table-stripped table-hover" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order</th>
                <th>Table</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Served</th>
                <th>Bill</th>
                <th>Paiment</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for order in orders %}

                <tr>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                        {{ order.order_id }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                        {{ order.table_id }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                        {{ order.created_at|date:"D, d M, Y" }}
                    </td>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                        {% if order.delivered %}
                            <a style="margin-right: 40px;color:black;" data-order="{{ order.order_id }}" class="served" href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a style="margin-right: 40px;color:black;" data-order="{{ order.order_id }}" class="served" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                    <form id="bill" method="POST" class="post-form" data-order="{{ order.order_id }}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ billform|crispy }}
                    <form>
                    </td>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                        <a style="margin-right: 40px;color:black;" data-order="{{ order.order_id }}" class="paiement" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></i></a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                        <a style="margin-right: 40px;color:black;" data-target="" class="" href="{% url 'cafe:update_order' order.order_id %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <a style="margin-right: 40px;color:black;" data-target="" class="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not pass a `request` to a `ModelForm`, you pass as first parameter the `data=…` parameter, so you construct a form without parameters for the GET request and with `request.POST` and `request.FILES` for the POST request:

```
def index(request):
    orders = Orders.objects.filter(paid=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #            no request ↓
        billform = BillForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if billform.is_valid():
            billform.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        billform = BillForm()   # ← no request

    return render(request, 'cafe/index.html', {'orders':orders,'billform':billform,})
```

Some people indeed override the `__init__` method to allow a request and do further processing with that, but a *vanilla* `ModelForm` does *not* take the request as parameter.